# Why privateKey*PublicKey get different result in Ed25519 with golang

Tags: key, dsa, ed25519

for result， i want to calculate a value X as apiKey with formula this

```
Pubkey1 = Privkey1 * G

Pubkey2 = Privkey2 * G
```

then we get

```
Privkey2 * Pubkey1 = Privkey1 * Pubkey2
```

also equal

```
Privkey2 * Privkey1 * G = Privkey1 * Privkey2 * G = X
```

then service and client can use X as key for signature。

i am new one in golang and ED25519 or ECDSA，if i was wrong，hope someone can figure out， thanks a lot！

the lib which i used is [crypto/ed25519](https://github.com/golang/crypto/tree/master/ed25519)

in this lib, i found a func GeDoubleScalarMultVartime(), it can calculate with formula

```
 r = a*A + b*B
```

i have no idea how to calculate X, so i consider if i set **b = 0**，

```
r = a*A + 0*B = a*A
```

and then i write some code to do a verification。

in lib crypto/ed25519, all kernel func located in folder internal，so i write some func to expose to me

```
// get ProjectiveGroupElement struct
func GetProjectiveGroupElement() edwards25519.ProjectiveGroupElement {
  var R edwards25519.ProjectiveGroupElement
  return R
}
// get GeDoubleScalarMultVartime function
func GeDoubleScalar(r *edwards25519.ProjectiveGroupElement, a * [32]byte, A *edwards25519.ExtendedGroupElement, b *[32]byte) {
    edwards25519.GeDoubleScalarMultVartime(r, a, A, b)
}
// return PublicKey correspondence ExtendedGroupElement immediate， which used in GeDoubleScalarMultVartime() as param A instead PublicKey
func GenerateKey(rand io.Reader) (PublicKey, PrivateKey, edwards25519.ExtendedGroupElement, error) {
    if rand == nil {
        rand = cryptorand.Reader
    }

    seed := make([]byte, SeedSize)
    if _, err := io.ReadFull(rand, seed); err != nil {
        var B edwards25519.ExtendedGroupElement
        return nil, nil, B, err
    }

    privateKey, A := NewKeyFromSeed(seed)
    publicKey := make([]byte, PublicKeySize)
    copy(publicKey, privateKey[32:])

    return publicKey, privateKey, A, nil
}
func NewKeyFromSeed(seed []byte) (PrivateKey, edwards25519.ExtendedGroupElement){
if l := len(seed); l != SeedSize {
    panic("ed25519: bad seed length: " + strconv.Itoa(l))
}

digest := sha512.Sum512(seed)
digest[0] &= 248
digest[31] &= 127
digest[31] |= 64

var A edwards25519.ExtendedGroupElement
var hBytes [32]byte
copy(hBytes[:], digest[:])
edwards25519.GeScalarMultBase(&A, &hBytes)
var publicKeyBytes [32]byte
A.ToBytes(&publicKeyBytes)
privateKey := make([]byte, PrivateKeySize)
copy(privateKey, seed)
copy(privateKey[32:], publicKeyBytes[:])

return privateKey, A
}
```

this is test code

```
package main

import (
        "crypto/rand"
        "golang.org/x/crypto/ed25519"
)

func main() {
    pubK, privK, localA, err := ed25519.GenerateKey(rand.Reader)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("error")
    }
    var R = ed25519.GetProjectiveGroupElement()
    var testpubKey [32]byte
    var testprivKey [32]byte
    for i,v := range pubK {
        testpubKey[i] = v
    }
    for i,v := range privK {
        if i < 32 {
            testprivKey[i] = v
        }
    }
    var apikey1 [32]byte
    var b [32]byte //set b = 0
    log.Printf("localA:%x\n", localA)
    pubK2, privK2, localB, err := ed25519.GenerateKey(rand.Reader)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("error")
    }
    var R2 = ed25519.GetProjectiveGroupElement()
    var testpubKey2 [32]byte
    var testprivKey2 [32]byte
    for i,v := range pubK2 {
        testpubKey2[i] = v
    }
    for i,v := range privK2 {
        if i < 32 {
            testprivKey2[i] = v
        }
    }
    var apikey2 [32]byte
    var b2 [32]byte //set b = 0
    log.Printf("localB:%x\n", localB)
    ed25519.GeDoubleScalar(&R2, &testprivKey2, &localA, &b2)
    R2.ToBytes(&apikey2)
    log.Printf("apikey2:%x\n", apikey2)
    log.Printf("privK2:%x\n", privK2)
    ed25519.GeDoubleScalar(&R, &testprivKey, &localB, &b)
    R.ToBytes(&apikey1)
    log.Printf("apikey:%x\n", apikey1)
    log.Printf("privK1:%x\n", privK)
   }
```

the result

```
2018/08/28 11:17:23 apikey2:c025975d177059792498509fc4d4a8586b0039273d80c62760cf52064d2555bb
2018/08/28 11:17:23 privK2:ebd70f9b2254bee1de3a105e274fc6b0d65da8d66b1ba47d760a47a3f8b5fe866bc1d3fa1db801b49dc5521cf0b440c84894dd03e2871581c2a84cdc9c92e037
2018/08/28 11:17:23 apikey:0cfd0e75e8ec990d93d2768b101c70c0bf42e38e869afacfcbc1e61183fdd03d
2018/08/28 11:17:23 privK1:5eee36a68309f49fb73e1a93338c3a9173ce37cf5b2c0d27d344b45a7f441c37cd021701c36a5322eacbba6e4a49eda2fbfa32bfe5baf859d9851ecff714721a
```

the two apikey are different, am i used lib in a wrong way?
or i have a wrong cognition with ed25519？
wish someone can give me help. thanks

my english is not so good, if you get confused with my discription，just figure it out， thanks again

Comment: It seems you want to compute a key agreement with ECDH; in that case, you should use the [`curve25519` package](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/curve25519)

Answer (score 1):

Out of the blue, I'd say it is probably because you are using `GenerateKey` which calls `NewKeyFromSeed` where the privateKey is actually copied from the seed `copy(privateKey, seed)`, and so you are using the seed instead of the `digest` actually used in `NewKeyFromSeed`, but in order to do the scalar trick you want to do, you have to use the actual private scalar in your computation, with the lower and upper bits sets as they should.

Instead modify your `NewKeyFromSeed` to do:

`copy(privateKey, digest)`

and maybe it will work as intended.

Disclaimer: I have only compiled this code in my head, so I might be off.
If you want more help, you should post a MWE, and maybe head to StackOverflow, since it is more like a debugging code question than a crypto question.